# WSL2 Linux: Numba CUDA Error_no_device however OS can see it

Tags: pytorch, gpu, numba, wsl-2

I am having issues with getting numba to work on my WSL installation. I am trying to use the OpenPCDet library from here (https://github.com/open-mmlab/OpenPCDet). However, I am getting this error. It seems like Numba isn't able to see the device. I also tried doing numba -s to get information, this is what I get (a subset is presented).

`__CUDA Information__
Error: CUDA device intialisation problem. Message:Error at driver init:
[100] Call to cuInit results in CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE:
Error class: 
ROC Information
ROC available                                 : False
Error initialising ROC due to                 : No ROC toolchains found.
No HSA Agents found, encountered exception when searching:
Error at driver init:
NUMBA_HSA_DRIVER /opt/rocm/lib/libhsa-runtime64.so is not a valid file path.  Note it must be a filepath of the .so/.dll/.dylib or the driver:
Conda Information
conda_build_version                           : not installed
conda_env_version                             : 4.12.0
platform                                      : linux-64
python_version                                : 3.9.7.final.0
root_writable                                 : True
Current Conda Env (Subset)
cudatoolkit               10.2.89              hfd86e86_1
cumm-cu102                0.2.8                    pypi_0    pypi
numba                     0.55.1                   pypi_0    pypi
pytorch                   1.7.1           py3.8_cuda10.2.89_cudnn7.6.5_0    pytorch`

Also, just to check whether WSL sees a GPU device, I used the command on this website (https://ubuntu.com/blog/getting-started-with-cuda-on-ubuntu-on-wsl-2). I get:

`Run "nbody -benchmark [-numbodies=]" to measure performance.
-fullscreen       (run n-body simulation in fullscreen mode)
-fp64             (use double precision floating point values for simulation)
-hostmem          (stores simulation data in host memory)
-benchmark        (run benchmark to measure performance)
-numbodies=    (number of bodies (>= 1) to run in simulation)
-device=       (where d=0,1,2.... for the CUDA device to use)
-numdevices=   (where i=(number of CUDA devices > 0) to use for simulation)
-compare          (compares simulation results running once on the default GPU and once on the CPU)
-cpu              (run n-body simulation on the CPU)
-tipsy=<file.bin> (load a tipsy model file for simulation)`

NOTE: The CUDA Samples are not meant for performance measurements. Results may vary when GPU Boost is enabled.

> Windowed mode
> Simulation data stored in video memory
> Single precision floating point simulation
> 1 Devices used for simulation
> GPU Device 0: "Pascal" with compute capability 6.1

> Compute 6.1 CUDA device: [NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti]
> 28672 bodies, total time for 10 iterations: 23.114 ms
> = 355.669 billion interactions per second
> = 7113.380 single-precision GFLOP/s at 20 flops per interaction

To provide further information. The nvidia-smi commands results in the following output:

`Sun May 22 16:37:56 2022
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 510.47.03    Driver Version: 512.15       CUDA Version: 11.6     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  On   | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 23%   26C    P8    11W / 250W |   1671MiB / 11264MiB |      3%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+`

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Can somebody help with this? Thanks!